# VS Code - put opening braces on new line

Tags: format, braces

I want the code to be formatted so that the open brace is put on the next line

as I ALT+SHIFT+F, the braces are set at the end of each line, which ruins readability

I want this

```
function () 
{
...
}
```

not this

```
function () {
...
}
```

how can I set that up in VS code ?

thanks